# how to use method from another class?

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

I think I have my method set properly to give me the total number of rooms but it won't compile. Where did I go wrong?

```java
public class Hotel {


    public static int singleRooms;
    public static int doubleRooms;
    public static int kingRooms;

    public Hotel(int numberSingleRooms, int numberDoubleRooms, int numberKingRooms) {
        singleRooms = numberSingleRooms;
        doubleRooms = numberDoubleRooms;
        kingRooms = numberKingRooms;
        }

    public static Hotel IvanHotel = new Hotel(1,3,5);


    int totalRooms = GetTotalRooms(IvanHotel);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(totalRooms);
    }

}

public class GetTotalRooms {

    public static int totalRooms;

    public int GetTotalRooms(Hotel yourHotel) {

        totalRooms = Hotel.singleRooms + Hotel.doubleRooms + Hotel.kingRooms;

        return totalRooms;

    }


}
```

What should I change in order to get it to compile? I am getting a cannot find symbol error and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you confused with the concept of `static`. You can't access non-static values from `static` context.

This code should fix things up

```
public class Hotel { 
    //...
    static int totalRooms = GetTotalRooms.getRoomsCount(IvanHotel);
    //...     
} 

class GetTotalRooms { 

    public static int getRoomsCount(Hotel yourHotel) {
        totalRooms = Hotel.singleRooms + Hotel.doubleRooms + Hotel.kingRooms;

        return totalRooms;
    } 
}
```

If you are a beginner I would suggest reading a lot of sample codes and start with basic concepts. Don't skip the basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a bit more reading to understand what the purpose of `static` is and why you'd use it. The way you wrote your code, you cannot call a non static method in a static way, you first need to create an instance of your `GetTotalRooms` first before you can do that `GetTotalRooms` so in the case of your code you'd write this

```
//...
private GetTotalRooms getTotalRooms = new GetTotalRooms();
int totalRooms = getTotalRooms.GetTotalRooms(IvanHotel);
//...
```

or you should follow what Doc said and make the method your calling `static` as well.

I'd also recommend you practice your naming conventions, 1st your class name sounds like a method name and then you have a method with the exact same name of your class, your `Hotel` class is fine but the `GetTotalRooms` class is the problem,

id rather name it something like `RoomsList` since you want to return the total amount of rooms you have in your `Hotel`

your class names should refer an Object, `GetTotalRooms` is not an object it's an equation in your case. Then your method name should refer to an action, and it should start with a lower case character, the name you chose for your method is good, it tells me exactly whats going to happen when I call it, just make it start with a lowercase so that it won't look like a class.

you can read more about it here:

[Coding like Shakespeare](https://dmitripavlutin.com/coding-like-shakespeare-practical-function-naming-conventions/)

and

[dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/best-practices-variable-and)